# rounded sine wave

Tags: calculus

Looking for a "puffy" version of the sine wave. I would like to create a sine-like graph which is less straight in the region around where the graph passes through the $x$ axis. Nesting the sine wave,$sin(sin(x))$ increases curvature near axis but decreases curvature at crest of wave. Scalar multiplying a sine wave will increase slope near $x$ axis but raises crest and increases curvature there, both of which I wish to avoid.

$y=\frac{\sin\left(\sin\left(\sin x\right)\right)}{.746}$ is a little flat at the crest and still kind of too straight near x intercepts.

Thank you.

Comment: Make a wave out of half-circles, using Fourier series

Comment: Or use any other function you like, with whatever curvature at endpoints. You can Fourier expand almost anything

Comment: Use $y=\text{sgn}(\sin x)|\sin x|^{1/p}$ for large $p$